# Vuex getter with an argument and computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm having trouble understanding how the code from a tutorial works.

I have the `EventComponent` component, which displays information about the event.
It uses a computed property which accesses Vuex store.

```html
<h4>This event is {{ getEvent(1) }}.</h4>
```

```js
export default  {
computed: {
  getEvent() {
    return this.$store.getters.getEventById
  }
}}
```

And this is my Vuex `index.js` file:

```js
export default createStore({
    state: {
        events: [{id: 1, title: "Last day"}]
    },
    mutations: {},
    getters: {
        getEventById: state => id => {
            return state.events.find(event => event.id === id)
        }
    },
    actions: {},
    modules: {}
})
```

The event info is displayed correctly. However, I'm confused by

1. How the computed property is able to accept an argument
2. How that argument is passed to the store getter, when the getter is not explicitly called with that argument

Could you help me understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How the computed property is able to accept an argument

Since `getEvent` just returns `this.$store.getters.getEventById` (which is a getter for a function), `getEvent` also returns a function, and can therefore be called the exact same way.

> 2. How that argument is passed to the store getter, when the getter is not explicitly called with that argument

Actually, the getter *is* indeed being called with that argument. As mentioned above `getEvent` is effectively an alias for `this.$store.getters.getEventById`, so `getEvent(1)` is the same as `this.$store.getters.getEventById(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Return a function from the computed property that takes the id as parameter:

```
<h4>This event is {{ getEvent(1) }}.</h4>

export default  {
computed: {
  getEvent() {
    return (id)=>this.$store.getters.getEventById(id)
  }
}}
```